# Google Suite Legacy edition is going away from 1 June 2022. What are the alternatives?

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, google, g-suite-business

I have been using Google Legacy edition (50 users) for myself and friends. I have been using YouTube, Google photos etc across all these accounts. Now I have less than 2 months to figure out what to do with my decade old data. If I don't migrate, Google will charge $300 every month. Google is also not giving the option to upgrade only few accounts. I will have to upgrade all 50.

Now I am looking at self hosting email on my domain using open source email servers and digital ocean.

Now I have following concerns:

1. How to migrate existing emails, chats, documents, files etc to another email system?
2. Alternatives to Google photos along with migration of 1000s of old photos
3. What are the closest free/open source alternatives to Google Suite? I know Zoho is one. And it is allowing upto 5 free users with 5 GBs storage.